# Ramda - Pick from an object and return an array

Tags: ramda.js

I have an array of ids which I need to use to get extended information from an object so it looks like this:

```
const arrayOne = [1, 2]

const objectOne =
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "reference": "ee",
      "content": {
        "blocks": [
          {
            "type": "plain",
            "data": {
              "text": "Lorem2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "reference": "dd",
      "content": {
        "blocks": [
          {
            "type": "plain",
            "data": {
              "text": "Lorem"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "id": 3,
      "reference": "dd",
      "content": {
        "blocks": [
          {
            "type": "plain",
            "data": {
              "text": "Lorem"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I am using Ramda to get only ids from arrays like this:

```
R.pick(arrayOne)(objectOne)
```

but then I get object and what I need is an array. How can I convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you probably need [`props`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#props) instead:

> Acts as multiple prop: array of keys in, array of values out. Preserves order.

```js
props(['1', '2'], {1: "foo", 2: "bar"});
//=>["foo","bar"]
```